# What is used first, .bashrc or .zshrc?

Tags: bash, debian, zsh

If you have both .bashrc or .zshrc how to know which one is preferred by the system? I am sure there is a chain of command or preference but do not know how to figure that out.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They’re not used together: `.bashrc` is read by Bash, `.zshrc` by Zsh, so which one is used depends on which shell you’re using.

Answer (score 2):

As the rc suffix implies these commonds are run after the respective programs they are named after. So if the user default is bash then bashrc is run but if you then start zsh then zshrc is run.
The login will start what ever is in the shell command.
Linux will recognize valid shells in /etc/shells
When using useradd the shell is determined by SHELL= in /etc/default/useradd

Answer (score 1):

There **is** as chain of files being sourced by the respective shells. This chain depends on various conditions (such as: Is it a login shell? Is it an interactive shell?). For the exact "chain" you should consult the shell's man page and see which chain is applicable in your case.